# counting in nested loops: more efficient?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following template, with nested loops. The template generates page numbers over multiple xml files (say: 20 files = chapters in my book). Numbering starts at @start=4.
$pagenr is the page counter. To count more efficiently, I keep the page count of previous files in $prevPage. Then I just add the number of pages in the xml file at hand in the inner loop.
Question: does it really work like that? Or is the $prevPage count updated in the inner loop nevertheless?
I see the XMLSpy debugger jumping back out of the inner loop to the `<xsl:variable name="prevPage" ....` line when processing the instructions in the inner loop.

```
<xsl:template match="lat:numberGroup">
<xsl:variable name="start" select="@start"/>
<xsl:variable name="format" select="@format"/>
<!-- newnav.xml must not be processed here, as it is being created -->
<xsl:for-each select="lat:entry[not(@pagenr) or not(@pagenr = 'no')]">
    <xsl:variable name="prevPage" select="number($start) + count((preceding-sibling::node())/document(lat:file)//lat:page)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="actFile" select="lat:file"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="document($actFile)//lat:page">
        <li>
            <a>
                <xsl:variable name="pagenr" select="number($prevPage) + count( ./preceding::lat:page  )"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                      <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($actFile,'\.')[1]"/>
                      .xhtml#pg
                      <xsl:value-of select="$pagenr"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:number value="$pagenr" format="{$format}"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The *jumping back* may be caused by the lazy evaluation of the XSLT processor. However, since XSLT *variables* are only set once and never changed afterwards any subsequent jumping back probably only demonstrates the laziness and does not represent an actual re-computation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I time my XSLT execution times to millisecond accuracy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783696/how-do-i-time-my-xslt-execution-times-to-millisecond-accuracy)

Answer (score 0):

How it works internally depends on which XSLT processor you are using. However, you're seriously out of luck if the processor adopts a strategy that is less efficient than the obvious strategy, which is to evaluate the variable at the point where the variable declaration occurs. As Marcus Rickert says, you're probably seeing the processor trying to do better than this, by delaying evaluation of the variable until it's needed (for example, it's not needed at all if the inner loop is executed zero times).

Incidentally, the expression `tokenize($actFile,'\.')[1]` could also be evaluated outside the inner loop. A smart processor will do that optimization for you, but if you want to be sure, you can do it by hand by creating another variable.